# GPIO pull up to different level

Tags: level-shifting, pullup, logic-level

I am using MSP430F235 which is supplied with 2.5V on DVCC. So, all its I/Os will be in 2.5V level. Now, I want to enable a LDO in which EN pin is tied to a different level (>2.5V is the battery supply as well as the input to LDO). Refer to this diagram[image]

1. I suppose the enable signal will now be in V_SPST level and not at 2.5V as high, Vih and Vil  of EN pin is okay. Kindly let me know whether my understanding is correct.
2. Will this affect the MSP430 in anyways or will there be any ground level offset in this pin?

Answer (score 2):

From the datasheet:

> V<sub>HI</sub> Enable high (enabled): MIN=0.9V, MAX=V<sub>IN</sub>

There is no problem driving this from a 2V5 CMOS output (\$2.5V \times 0.7 = 1.75V \$).